# Pagination in Elasticsearch PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have an array in Elasticsearch which returns 400 records:

```
$result = $search->search($keyword);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); exit;
```

I'm running a foreach loop for `$results` to display. How can I add pagination of Elasticsearch?

below is code for search:

```
$params = [
            'index' => $this->client->getIndex(),
            'type'  => $this->client->getType(),
            "from" => 0, "size" => 100,
            "scroll" => "1m",

            'body'  => [
           "query" => [
               "bool" => [
                  "must" => [
                     [
                          "multi_match" => [
                              "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name"],
                              "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                              "query" => $query
                          ]
                     ],
                     [
                          "term"=> ["cat_type_id"=>1]
                     ]
                  ]
               ]
            ]
            ],
       ];
```

Querying in BD returns 400 records but elastic search giving 100 as I added size. How Do i scroll to another page?

my URl: http://example.com/ppm2.0/search.html?q=samsung

Comment: @Twinfriends I am trung to add Size and From after url but without any success..LIke..?size=5&from=5 
my URL : http://example.com/ppm2.0/search.html?q=samsung

Comment: To paginate you need to know "How mant total record", "how many records per page", "what is the current page", you can offset your "from" based on `current page x records per page" https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html

Comment: @Scuzzy .. I have given size in search so How can I get total number of records without size in same search. I have 400 records but total records showing 100 only.